# Possible bug when upvoting your own anwser

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, upvotes

I am not sure if this question should be posted in meta or not, apologies if not.

So I just wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43228495/6188901) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998946/hdf5-viewer-for-lzf-compressed-arrays/43228495) although it was asked some time ago, because I think the answer can be helpful for future reference. Still I thought the other answer was useful, so I was going to up-vote it, but by mistake I clicked on mine. I got a message saying *"You can't vote for your own post"*, which is normal, but at the same time the vote count went from 0 to 2, which is weird. If I click again either on up-vote or a down-vote on my answer nothing other than the *"You can't vote for your own post"* message happens.

Comment: This is not a bug. That counter just refreshed and ___other users___ voted on your post already.

Comment: I would guess it was from other having voted and your action updating the vote total.

Comment: I see... My bad, I thought chances of 2 people up-voting my answer in such a short period of time were almost none.

Comment: When you answered the question, that bumped it to the top of the Active questions queue, which likely brought new attention to the question. So while you shouldn't expect it, it isn't odd for a new answer to an old question to get feedback right away. (It also might have gone to the Late Answers review queue, which would mean at least a few users would have looked at it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no bug here. Two other people *also* upvoted your answer *around the same time*.

A web-socket connection updates post scores in near real time; when you accidentally voted on yours, the score on the post was also updated to reflect the current score for your post.